How to Configure Debian Server with ISP-Delegated Static IPs?
I'm setting up a Debian server to act as both a router and a server, but I've encountered issues with my ISP's unique static IP assignment method. Here's the situation:
I have been assigned two static IPs: 66.161.243.109 and 66.161.243.110 with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252. My goal is to assign 66.161.243.109 to the Debian server.
The Problem:
My ISP uses a method called subnet routing (or IP address delegation) instead of directly assigning static IPs to the router's WAN interface. The router dynamically receives an IP address that serves as the gateway for the static IP block. Static IPs are routed through this dynamic WAN IP rather than being assigned directly to the router.
This essentially means that:

The static IPs are configured on devices behind a router.
The WAN IP dynamically assigned to a router by the ISP is used as a gateway for the static IPs.

I understand this setup conceptually, but I am having trouble making it work in practice.
Current Configuration:
Here is my /etc/network/interfaces setup:
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
    pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/network/iptables.rules

# Virtual interfaces for static IP addresses on eno1
auto eno1:1
iface eno1:1 inet static
    address 66.161.243.109
    netmask 255.255.255.252

# The 2nd network interface as DHCP router
auto eno2
iface eno2 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0

What I've Tried:
To ensure outbound packets use the static IP address, I added this iptables rule:
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -j SNAT --to-source 66.161.243.109

However, this caused:

100% packet loss when trying to ping external addresses.
curl ifconfig.me hangs indefinitely.

I've tried various configurations and workarounds, but I haven't been able to make it work.
Question:

How can I configure my Debian server to properly use 66.161.243.109 for outgoing traffic while keeping eno1 functional with the ISP's dynamically assigned IP?
Do I need to adjust routing, NAT, or iptables settings to make this work?
Alternatively, am I forced to use a dedicated router between the modem and my server to use the static IP addresses?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Can you verify with tcpdump -n -i eno1 to see 1) what packets are being sent when you run the curl command, 2) what packets are being received? I kind of suspect that the ISP hasn't correctly set up routing of the addresses at all, so it might be that your server is sending packets from the desired address but isn't receiving anything back...
